# Unity Shader Graph - Grandient following the object shape

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I'm learning unity and I'm very new to shaders. I'm doing a lot of tutorials and already did some things, but I have a problem that I'm not able to solve.
The problem I have is that I want (if it's possible) to make a gradient (or a texture, material, etc.) follow the object shape. I have a cilinder where I can control the position of the gradient, the spread, etc. But when the object have some curves it fills like this:

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vczDa.png)

But I what that the grandient in this case, takes the shape of the object, filling like this:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z714.png)

It's that possible? How? Have this a correct name to search for? (I'm sorry, English is not my mother tongue).

This is the current shader graph I'm using:
[Current Shader Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lnrx.png)

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to do what you want based on position. You need UV mapping.

Comment: Hi, I am disappointed but thank you very much for the answer.